# Prove that if all Fourier coefficients are zero then the function is zero

Tags: real-analysis

I want prove that if $f \in L^1(\mathbb T) $ and $\hat{f}(n)=0 \quad \forall n$ then $f=0$ .

Given $F_N(x)$ the Fejer kernel I know that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |(f*F_N)(x)-f(x)| dx =0$

Is $f*F_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f*D_n(x)$ with $D_n(x) $ Dirichlet Kernel?

So $f*D_n(x)=\sum_{|j|\le n} \hat{f}(j) e^{ijx}=0$ because all Fourier coefficients are zero

Then $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(x)| dx =0$ so the function is zero.

Comment: Yes, I have to use it

Comment: Your proof is correct, minus the fact that the integral with the Fejer Kernel isn't equal to $0$ but rather converges to $0$. Convolution is a bilinear operator, so $f*F_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum f*D_n$.

And as you noticed, every term in the RHS is zero, so for every N, $f*F_N=0$.

Since $f*F_N$ converges to $f$ i L¹, $f$ is zero.

Comment: You can be in $L^1$, and not in $L^2$ !

Comment: If  the function is in $L^2(\mathbb T) $ can I use Parseval's equality?

Comment: If it's L², Parseval's equality implies the result, yes.